# change bib-style plaindin with fullstop at the end

Tags: bibtex

I use the bibliographystyle `plaindin`. The resulting bibliography looks very much how I want it to be, but there are two problems:

1. Having more than one author the output is

   > author 1 ; author 2 ; ...

   but I want it to be like this:

   > author 1; author 2; ...

   without the space before the semicolon.
2. I want to have a fullstop at the end of each entry.

Is there an easy way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of `plaindin.bst` in a place where BibTeX will find it, say `mayplaindin.bst`, and open it.

1) In line 473, change

```
{ " ; " * t * }
```

to

```
{ "; " * t * }
```

i.e., remove the space in front of `;`

In line 480, change

```
{ " ; " * t * }
```

to

```
{ "; " * t * }
```

i.e., remove again the space in front of `;`

The code in lines 474--477 must be commented out, so change from

```
{ numnames #2 >
  { " " * }
  'skip$
if$
```

to

```
{ % numnames #2 >
  %   { " " * }
  %   'skip$
  % if$
```

That removes the space after the second-to-last author.

2) Change line 301, from

```
{ write$
```

to

```
{ "." * write$
```

Then you can use `\bibliographystyle{myplaindin}`.

Comment: Close! The fullstopp works. The space before the ";" changed only for the first two authors of the first entry. But my first entry has 4 authors. The other entries are as bad as before.

Comment: I tried to change line 480 as well, which removes the space for the other entries. But still in my first entry, there is the space behind the third name.

Comment: @Greyfox Sorry, my mistake. Please see the updated answer.